# Is there a quicker way to write $\cos (n\theta)$ in terms of $\cos \theta$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, polynomials

> Im writing $\cos 8\theta$ in terms of $\cos \theta$ using De Moivre's Theorem

$$\cos 8\theta= \Re {(\cos\theta+ i \sin \theta)^8}$$

> Let $s=\sin \theta$ and $c=\cos \theta$
>
> $$=c^8 -28c^6(1-c^2)+70c^4(1-c^2)^2-28c^2(1-c^2)^3+(1-c^2)^4$$

I find it really tedious especially to **expand the brackets**

and then remove these  brackets and simplify. This is doable, but tedious. Is there a way to do it faster? What if n is larger than 8,  surely there must be a quicker method, otherwise it would be worse.

Comment: It's called De Moivres, not De Movier. And you could use the formula for binomial expansion instead of expanding by hand.

Comment: @AlexH. Not De Moivre (De Moivre's)?

Comment: My fault, yes it's De Moivre's

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the recursive relation involving [Chebychev polynomials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html):

$$
T_{n+1}(X) = 2XT_n(X) - T_{n-1}(X)
\\
T_n(\cos \theta) = \cos n\theta
$$

---

Proof: first prove existence of such polynomials.

Then the identity
$$
\cos ((n+1)\theta) + \cos ((n-1)\theta) = 2\cos \theta \cos n\theta
$$

Comment: (+1) Thank you very much. Im reading about this on wolfram.

Comment: done ;) :D thank you a lot